# Laravel : symlink(): No such file or directory on cPanel

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, shared-hosting

Im trying todo `php artisan storage:link` on terminal in cPanel. It always show "symlink(): No such file or directory".

I have also tried the method call Artisan on route : `Route::get('/tes', function() { Artisan::call('storage:link'); });`. Problem still same.

Deleted folder storage on `public_html` and do `php artisan storage:link`, but still not working.

Add function Register() on app->providers->AppServiceProvider.php :

```
$this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
   return base_path('../public_html');
});
```

This is my `index.php` on folder `public_html`.

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Folder Structure view : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd0nK.png)

folder laravel view : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPukb.png)

folder public_html view : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKaOu.png)

I managed to do this `ln -s /path/to/target /path/to/shortcut`, but i think its not perfect. because the link must display storage. If i success using `php artisan storage:link`, the link doesn't have to show storage. like example.com/storage/folderimage/abc.jpg and example.com/folderimage/abc.jpg

Comment: Laravel folder should be inside of your public_html. Is it there?

Comment: i did a separate folder. So laravel folder is outside on public_html.

Answer (score 0):

According to the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPukb.png I can't see the public folder inside laravel directory.

The following steps will fix the problem inChaAllah:

- Upload the public directory inside your laravel project.
- Delete `public/storage` directory if exists.
- Run the following:

```bash
     $ cd laravel
     $ php artisan storage:link
```

A symlink for `storage` is created inside `laravel/public` directory.

- Copy the contents of `laravel/public/` directory into `public_html`.
- Update the path of laravel app inside `public_html/index.php`
- Comment out the `path.public` binding inside `AppServiceProvider.php`.

Comment: I have do point 1,, so `laravel/public` is already on `public_html`.
for point 2, i have declared my `public_html/index.php`.

Comment: I already do `Deleted folder storage on public_html and do php artisan storage:link, but still not working.`

Comment: Please put a snap of `public_html` contents

Comment: just it https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKaOu.png

Comment: or this https://prnt.sc/-BhGQQi5TKgf

Comment: You missed step 3, where storage dir doesn't exist on public_html dir

Comment: i have create it and delete it again.. still problem `symlink(): No such file or directory`

Comment: is it good if my file .env `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public` ?